# How to extend lifetime of password, generated by ref.resetPassword()?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to implement login system so it uses random password that is being generated by `ref.resetPassword()`.

Problem is that the random password becomes invalid after 24 hours. 
Tried to change the session length to 24 months (in Login&Auth dashboard tab), but it didn't affect the random password lifetime.

Is there a way to extend lifetime of the random password? Thank you!

Comment: Firebase Authentication currently doesn't have an option to extend the lifetime of/refresh a token. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/wAcJFfQlFeg/IUuJXNcgDHgJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password-reset token that Firebase generates when you call `resetPassword()` expires after 24 hours. That time period is not configurable, nor can the token be extended.