# Firebase.resetPassword() password lifetime

Tags: angularjs, web, firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularJS and firebase as backend to create my simple web app.
When .resetPassword() method is called, an email which contains a temporary password is sent to user, so he can login into an app. 
According to the following resource, lifetime of the temporary password is 24 hours:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/resetpassword.html

So, I have a question - what happens after the temporary password expires? Is it just discarded and an old password can be used again?..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes there is a workaround to this..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846971/how-to-extend-lifetime-of-password-generated-by-ref-resetpassword?rq=1

Comment: Once the password reset token expires, it cannot be used anymore. Neither creating a password reset token nor its expiry have any influence on the existing password as far as I know.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - so, when the the token is emailed, it serves as an additional password, while the old password can still be used, right?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can change the users password, and then email it to him manually.. So lets say when they register to your app it becomes in the following order:

```
username---
          Username
          Password
          Email
          UID
```

So then when the user clicks on resetPassword you have to generate a random password, and send him a email... So first lets tackle sending the email:

First of register for [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/signup/)

```
1. register for Mandrill to get an API key
2. load jQuery
3. use $.ajax to send an email
```

So this is how it will be layed out :

```
function randomPassword(){
    var length = 8,
        charset = "abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Dont forget to add this to your script tag:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

So you can send emails:

And:

```
$.ajax({
  type: “POST”,
  url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
  data: {
    ‘key’: ‘YOUR API KEY HERE’,
    ‘message’: {
      ‘from_email’: ‘YOUR@EMAIL.HERE’,
      ‘to’: [
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_1@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          },
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_2@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘ANOTHER RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          }
        ],
      ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
      ‘subject’: ‘Password generated’,
      ‘html’: ‘This is your Newly generated password’ + randomPassword
    }
  }
 }).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 });
```

More info on the sending email part [here](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782#.qlinfpnhn)

If you are trying to do this only using firebase, that is not possible as frank said here: [How to extend lifetime of password, generated by ref.resetPassword()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846971/how-to-extend-lifetime-of-password-generated-by-ref-resetpassword?rq=1)

Comment: You can only change the password by calling [`changePassword()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/changepassword.html), which requires that you know the old/current password. So I don't think this applies.

Comment: This does apply... Did you read my logic correctly @FrankvanPuffelen?  The user stores the password when they register and can play with it as i mentioned above.. And yea you could do changePassword(), and in the sucess callback get the password but mine is just another way...

Comment: Are you proposing to store the password in the database (e.g. under `/users/$uid`)? In that case,the flow could work. But I would not recommend storing the user's password in your database. One of the reasons for using Firebase Authentication is that you don't have to take responsibility for storing the user's password.

Comment: Thats what i said yes.. And your right.. Well you can just ask the user for password then check if it is right by doing checkPassword(); , then you can get the new password he want to change to, and do the proposed plan above @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thank you, @Dsafds, for such a detailed response :) however, I do not need to implement any additional features for my app, just wanted to understand what happens to the token as it expires. And storing data in database does actually seem to be a less safe approach. Cheers anyways!